# Xcode is throwing me an error in swift

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm following a tutorial(http://youtube.com/watch?v=xvvsG9Cl4HA 19 min 20sec) and to make his code look neat he puts some on a ew line like this

```
if let myPlacement = myPlacements?.first
        {

            let myAddress = "\(myPlacement.locality) \
            (myPlacement.country) \
            (myPlacement.postalCode)"
        }
```

. But when I try I get an error

```
unterminated string literal
```

and

```
consecutive statements on a line must be seperated by a ';'
```

but the guy in the tutorial has done it the exact same way. What's going on? 
I'm using the latest swift and and latest xcode 7.2 any help would be apreciated

if I write everything on the same line like this

```
if let myPlacement = myPlacements?.first
        {

            let myAddress = "\(myPlacement.locality) \(myPlacement.country) \(myPlacement.postalCode)"
        }
```

it works fine though

Comment: You need provide your tutorial, so we can tell you, it is some typo of you, or your tutorial is error, or it is outdate.

Comment: @Tinyfool  youtube.com/watch?v=xvvsG9Cl4HA it's a video from Oct 25 2015 at about 19 min 20sec's in

Answer (score 11):

> if I write everything on the same line like this

Well, there's your answer. You are not permitted to break up a string literal into multiple lines as you are doing in your first example. There are languages that permit this, but Swift is not one of them. This is not legal:

```
let s = "hello
there"
```

There is no magic line-continuation character which, placed at the end of the first line, would make that legal.

*If the window is narrower than the line*, the *editor* may *wrap* the line, for display purposes; but *you* cannot put actual line breaks inside a string literal.

You can work around this by combining (concatenating) multiple string literals, if you think that makes for greater legibility. This, for example, is legal:

```
let myAddress = "\(myPlacement.locality) " + 
    "\(myPlacement.country) " + 
    "\(myPlacement.postalCode)"
```

Comment: but in the tutorial he's doing it the same way that gives merrors. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvvsG9Cl4HA it's a video from Oct 25 2015 at about 19 min 20sec's in

Comment: @losee Maybe the tutorial guy also gets compiler errors. Have you watched the whole video? Maybe he changes it later.

Comment: @Arc676no he doesnt. it runs and there are no red dots on the side. Not familiar with swift syntax. Started yesterday. but in the video he gets no errors

Comment: why would you guys down vote a legit question from someone who started swift yesterday following a tutorial on you tube? Some of you guys need to get your heads out of your ass. probably was matt telling me it can't be done and I'm watching the video and the guy is doing it

Comment: @losee He (video guy) doesn't actually insert line breaks, it's just that the swift editor wraps the text for him so it will fit in his editor window. If you try to write a really long expression in your editor, you'll see that the editor do this automatic "wrapping"---purely as a visual aid---to ensure you needn't scroll your editor context horizontally

Comment: @dfri if you watch the video you can hear him hit the key and still be on the same line. if the computer was doing it I would send him to the other line and you wouldn't hear him hit the space key. It's fine, I'll find out. But thank you

Comment: @losee I think you misunderstood me; he can write continuously and the editor will wrap the long lines dynamically. I suggest you try this out on your own in XCode editor before searching for another explanation. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: @dfri I understood you, but he's talking, and typing while he pauses.

Comment: @losee Okay, I looked at the video. What's happening is covered by the fourth sentence in my answer: `If the window is narrower than the line, the editor may wrap the line, for display purposes; but you cannot put actual line breaks inside a string literal.` He is merely hitting _space_ and the _window_ (which is quite narrow) is soft-wrapping as he continues to type. That's different from what _you_ are doing, inserting a return character (i.e. hard-wrapping).

Comment: @losee I made you a video showing how making the window narrower causes soft-wrapping in _exactly_ the same places as the tutorial: https://youtu.be/_rs1DSeEj0M

Comment: @matt thanks for the response. Still don't think my question warranted a down vote, but thanks

Comment: @losee My advice: stop moaning about the downvote. That's just how Stack Overflow works. You can't locate the downvoter; you're talking to empty air. It's an anonymous crowdsourced environment. You'll just have to get used to that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I look your video tutorial carefully. You have a misunderstanding here.

[image]

You must pay attention to the video, the code in this picture is not break lines because he add a return here, it is because his screen is too narrow.

So, the real code is

```
let myAddress = "\(myPlacement.locality) \(myPlacement.country) \(myPlacement.postalCode)"
```

Please watch it carefully.

And you may need know first, `\` in `\(myPlacement.locality)` is a escape character, it means to get the value of `myPlacement.locality` and put in the string.